# CentOS and iptables Logging

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, logging, centos6

I am working with some CentOS rules and would like to be able to log the dropped items from iptables out to a separate file.  What is the best way to setup CentOS to log dropped iptables matches to a log file under /var/log that is not equal to the messages file.

If it matters, I am using both CentOS 5.5 and newer as well as CentOS 6.x.

Comment: I am not sure if this could be done by extending or changing the configuration of rsyslog or not?  If so, I would be interested in seeing some examples or how to configure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to redirect iptables output to a separate file.

Iptables supports a a ULOG target, that will send all log messages to a netlink socket instead of the kernel syslog output.  There [are applications](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) that can read from that ULOG socket and store your logs in databases or files.

For logging with the LOG target you can do things like set a prefix to the log entry, with `--log-prefix`, and if you are using a more advanced syslog daemon then you can [filter based](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) on that pattern, and save the entries into a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am using rsyslog-4.6.2-2.el6.x86_64 that comes with CentOS.